# Windows 10 Pro activation suddenly lost

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-activation

One year ago I bought an Asus Notebook with preinstalled Windows 10 Home which I upgraded to Windows 10 Pro (upgrade bought in the Microsoft store). The activation of Windows 10 Pro worked with no problems.

After one year without any problems, I now get the message "Activate Windows Go to Settings to activate Windows" in the lower right corner of the desktop.

When I go to Settings / Update & Security / Activation is says:

```
Edition: Windows 10 Pro

Activation: Windows is not activated

We can't activate Windows on this device because you don't have a valid digital license or product key.

Error code: 0x803F7001
```

ShowKeyPlus gives the following results:

```
Product Name:   Windows 10 Pro
Version:    16299.726 (64-bit OS)
Product ID: 00330-80000-00000-AA663
Installed Key:  VK7JG-NPHTM-C97JM-9MPGT-3V66T (which is the generic Windows 10 Pro key)
Original Key:   xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx (a  Windows 10 key, same as OEM Key)
Original Edition: Win 10 RTM Core OEM:DM
OEM Key:       xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx (a  Windows 10 key, same as Original Key)
OEM Edition:    Win 10 RTM Core OEM:DM
```

I did not change any hardware nor did I change or install any software except the quality and driver updates for Windows Version 1709.

The last Windows updates have been installed on November 8, 2018, a day before the activation problem showed up:

quality updates

- update for Adobe Flash Player for Windows 10 Version 1709 for
  x64-based Systems (KB4462930)
- 2018-10 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1709 for x64-based
  Systems (KB4462918)

driver updates

- Intel Corporation - SoftwareComponent - 4/16/2018 12:00:00 AM -
  20.50.3
- Intel Corporation - Extension - 3/1/2018 12:00:00 AM - 1.0.0.5

other updates

- Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool x64 - October 2018 (KB890830)

I made a full system scan with Avira and Windows Defender. No malware has been found.

What could be the cause of the problem?

How to solve the problem?

Comment: This is a known problem of the latest Windows 10 update. No fix yet from Microsoft unfortunately.

Comment: @Cutter - The problem was with the activation servers, which has already been resolved, the known fix is to simply click on the link to activate the installation.  This has nothing to do with an update, it affected, nearly everyone no matter which cumulative update they had installed.

Answer (score 3):

> What could be the cause of the problem?

This was a known problem with Microsoft's activation servers.  The problem has already been resolved, in order to activate your instance of Windows, you should do the following.

> 1. Go to Settings
> 2. Navigate to **Update & Security > Activation**
> 3. Click the link for the troubleshooter

[Microsoft acknowledges Windows 10 Pro licenses being mistakenly deactivated [Update]](https://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-acknowledges-some-windows-10-pro-licenses-being-mistakenly-deactivated)

> I bought the pro key in the Microsoft store, but now ShowKeyPlus shows the generic Windows 10 Pro key.

It sounds like you should simply change the product key.

> 1. Open **Settings**.
> 2. Click on **Update & security**.
> 3. Click on **Activation**.
> 4. Click the **Change product key** link.

[How to change Windows 10's product key using Settings](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-product-key-windows-10)

Comment: Via the MS chat I got a new key for Windows 10 pro and entered it. Windows 10 pro is now activated. However the keys shown in ShowKeyPlus (as shown in my original question above) including the Installed Key VK7JG-NPHTM-C97JM-9MPGT-3V66T remain the same. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to activate it over a phone.
Please follow the steps:
1. Press Windows Key + R, and type **Slui 4**. Press enter.
2. Select your country or region from the list.
3. Call the **Toll free** number and enter your **Installation ID**.
4. After the call, you will get confirmation ID.
5. Choose **Enter confirmation ID** and type the one that you received.
6. Click **Activate**.